# Model fitting, get weird lines rather than points

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im trying to fit a linear model here, yet instead of points plotted with geom_point i get a line through every datapoint. Does anyone know how to solve this so i get points rather than this jagged line. Data and code below

data snippet

```
height weight   age gender
    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <fct> 
 1   152.   47.8    63 1     
 2   140.   36.5    63 0     
 3   137.   31.9    65 0     
 4   157.   53.0    41 1     
 5   145.   41.3    51 0     
 6   164.   63.0    35 1     
 7   149.   38.2    32 0     
 8   169.   55.5    27 1     
 9   148.   34.9    19 0     
10   165.   54.5    54 1     
11   154.   49.9    47 0     
12   151.   41.2    66 1
```

code used;

```
linear_mod = lm(weight ~ height, data = weight_height)

#plot predictions
#function
plot_predicts <- function(model, df) {

#make predictions
preds <- predict(model, df)

#plot
df %>% 
   mutate(predicted=preds) %>% 
   dplyr::select(weight, height, predicted) %>% 
   pivot_longer(-height) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=height, y=value, colour=name)) +
   geom_point(data=. %>% filter(name=="height")) +
   geom_line(data=. %>% filter(name!="height"))
}

plot_predicts(linear_mod, weight_height)
```

the data snipet might not be enough to re-run the graph i get so i have attatched it below
[image]

what i'm looking to get (with a linear line though);
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=height, y=weight)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is good, i do also want to try and understand what is causing my original code to form the jagged lines if anyone knows why that is, as i need to use it on more complex (non-linear models)

Comment: @Joe You are getting the jagged lines because those lines are the original data, what you are *not* getting is the points, `filter(name=="height")` keeps nothing, there are no names equal to `"height"`.

Comment: Gotcha, only trouble is removing that also gives me points on my predictions line. I could do this a more simple way but wanted to try and sort this for quadratic models after

Comment: height should have been changed to weight here, much better then

Answer (score 2):

You are complicating the linear fitting and prediction too much, `ggplot2` has layer [`geom_smooth`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html) that does all the work automatically.

```r
weight_height <- read.table(text = "
height weight   age gender
 1   152.   47.8    63 1     
 2   140.   36.5    63 0     
 3   137.   31.9    65 0     
 4   157.   53.0    41 1     
 5   145.   41.3    51 0     
 6   164.   63.0    35 1     
 7   149.   38.2    32 0     
 8   169.   55.5    27 1     
 9   148.   34.9    19 0     
10   165.   54.5    54 1     
11   154.   49.9    47 0     
12   151.   41.2    66 1
", header = TRUE)
weight_height$gender <- factor(weight_height$gender)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

#plot predictions function
plot_predicts <- function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "lm", se = FALSE)
}

plot_predicts(weight_height)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>